# Oracle APEX Interactive Report Column Hyperlinks & Variables

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm using APEX 5 for the first time and trying to link users to the same page from an interactive report column.

The page being linked to will display different data, depending on which row user clicked.

I don't know what data to depend on to generate the new page, my thoughts are to write (a href) statements but not sure how variables are supposed to be stored this way.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong approach, in my opinion.

You should have done this:

- create a new page
- choose the "Report" page type
- choose "Report with Form on table"

It'll create both Interactive Report and a "linked" Form which will be used for the purpose you described. You don't even have to write a single line of code, Apex will do everything for you. You'd just click the icon at the beginning of the Interactive Report row, and it'll lead you to the Form and display values related to that very row.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice!
I'm now wondering how do I determine which record I clicked? because now I want to replace the edit report information page with a new report that is created depending on which record clicked. What variable is there for me place into (where id = ?)

Comment: Sorry, do you know how do I determine which record I clicked? because now I want to replace the edit report information page with a new report that is created depending on which record clicked. What variable is there for me place into (where id = ?) thank you so much

Comment: If you open Interactive Report page (in Apex), navigate to its "Attributes". There's the "Link" property which describes what to do when you click the link column - probably "Link to custom target", and the target is (for example) "Page 30". Click the target button. The "Link Builder" window will open, and in there you'll see that the target page's item (for example, `P30_ID`) is set to current (Interactive Report's) value `#ID#`. I'd suggest you to do the same.

Comment: Littefoot's pointing you in the right direction. For more on this, I'm pretty sure the Apex Tutorials include this, as it's a fairly basic Apex concept.

Comment: really appreciate your help, One last question, how can we determine the username of the currently logged in user from our custom authentication scheme? we tried many times

Comment: Use Apex variable `:APP_USER`

Comment: We solved it finally, many thanks for your time, really appreciated!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, we tried to use the values set in target page's item, e.g. P30_ID and #ID# into our where clause in sql. But it's not allowing me to do so. How should I use these values into sql query?

Comment: I don't think that you can do that. On a target page (it is a form, right?) you should use the *automatic row fetch* process (its position is Pre-rendering - After header). Create a sample [Interactive Report + Form] and see how the Wizard does it - then copy that to your real form. Though, I don't understand why you're doing it that way, instead of using built-in Apex capabilities ...

Comment: Which built-in Apex capability allow me to do this? I simply want another page (with IR report on it) to be created, depending on which IR row clicked. I created a Report with Form on Table as you suggested and changed the Form to an IR instead, but I can't figure how to determine which row clicked in my new IR being generated.